# vue js Перенос данных из одного массива в новый и наоборот

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Хотелось реализовать следующее: если watched = true, то данные из первого массива удаляются и отрисовываются в новом массиве и наоборот
Watched - это чекбокс
Как можно реализовать подобное?

```js
new Vue({
    el: ".movieProject",
    data: {
        film: "",
        watched: false,
        movies: [
            {
                film: "Мстители, 2012",
                watched: false
            },
            {
                film: "Первому игроку приготовиться, 2018",
                watched: false
            },
            {
                film: "Аватар, 2009",
                watched: false
            }
        ],
        favouritesMovies: [
            {
                film: "Прибытие, 2016",
                watched: true 
            }
        ]
    }

methods: {
        watchedMovie: function (movie) {
       
        };
    },
```

```html
 <ul 
                            id="ul"
                            class="movieProject__movieRandomList__list__items">
                            <li 
                                id="li"
                                v-for="(movie, index) in movies"
                                v-bind:class="{done: isWatched(movie)}"
                                :key="index"
                            >
                                <input 
                                    type="checkbox" 
                                    class="movieProject__movieRandomList__list__items--checkboxIcon" 
                                    v-on:click="watchedMovie(movie)" 
                                    v-model="movie.watched"
                                    v-bind:id="'done' + index"
                                >
                                <label 
                                    class="movieProject__movieRandomList__list__items__text"
                                    v-bind:for="'done' + index"
                                >{{ movie.film }}
                                </label>
                                    <button 
                                        v-on:click="addToFavourites()"
                                        class="movieProject__movieRandomList__list__items__icons
                                        movieProject__movieRandomList__list__items__icons--liked">
                                    </button>
                                    <button 
                                        v-on:click="disliked()"
                                        class="movieProject__movieRandomList__list__items__icons
                                        movieProject__movieRandomList__list__items__icons--disliked">
                                    </button>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <div>
                            <h2>Просмотренные</h2>
                        </div>
                        <ul>
                            <li
                                id="li"
                                v-for="(movie, index) in favouritesMovies"
                                v-bind:class="{done: isWatched(movie)}">
                                <input 
                                    type="checkbox" 
                                    class="movieProject__movieRandomList__list__items--checkboxIcon" 
                                    v-on:click="watchedMovie(movie)" 
                                    v-model="movie.watched"
                                    v-bind:id="'done' + index"
                                >
                                <label 
                                    class="movieProject__movieRandomList__list__items__text"
                                    v-bind:for="'done' + index"
                                >{{ movie.film }}
                                </label>
                                    <button 
                                        v-on:click="addToFavourites()"
                                        class="movieProject__movieRandomList__list__items__icons
                                        movieProject__movieRandomList__list__items__icons--liked">
                                    </button>
                                    <button 
                                        v-on:click="disliked()"
                                        class="movieProject__movieRandomList__list__items__icons
                                        movieProject__movieRandomList__list__items__icons--disliked">
                                    </button>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

С помощью `watchers`. Помимо methods, computed и data есть свойство `watch`. Работает просто:

```
watch: {
  watched() { // это точное имя переменной, за изменениями которой мы смотрим
    newArray = [...oldArray]; // когда что-то меняется, отрабатывает эта логика
    oldArray = [];
  }
}
```

Подробнее тут https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers
или же навесить на чекбокс событие `@change="function"`. Что-то вроде

```
<input @change="cleanArray" type="checkbox">

methods: {
  cleanArray() {
    newArray = [...oldArray];
    oldArray = [];
  }
}
```